# Most effecient way to export data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bigdata

We are using mongo (self hosted, not a managed service) as our data store, but our data volume is far too big for mongo to handle. We are going to transition to Google's big table service, but now we have a problem: we have to do a one time export of 65 million records (~200GB) from a single mongo collection. We also want to do it in a couple hours to reduce the amount of data that will have been updated in that time.

I'm not very concerned with writing to big table as it has seemed pretty fast, is easy to parallelize, and is actually designed to handle this much data. The hard part is reading from mongo.

What we have tried:
Run a query in node (no sorts/filters), run the output through a transform, then upload to big table. As it turns out, this approach was extremely naive. We blew out the CPU on the box with no obvious bottlenecks, however even if we skip the whole writing part, the reading part is still really slow.

The next options all revolved around the general idea of 'do a full database dump, split it into even-sized chunks, process it in parallel.'

Use mongoexport. This is still really slow, but substantially better then the db query.

Use mongodump. This was faster than mongoexport, but still on the slow side. Also, I don't know how easy it is to parse the files.

I have been having difficulty identifying what the bottlenecks are. CPU is generally high, but not maxed out (except for the naive approach mentioned above). As expected, disk I/O is also generally very high. I also don't think I can control that because it is on the cloud (GCP).

I'm mostly trying to get other ideas/approaches here, although I am fully aware that this may simply not be possible, but I would like a second opinion before making that conclusion.

Comment: This is hard to help with as you've provided not even a snippet of code and only discussed failed approaches with no info about how you naively implemented the Node approach. The piece I'd like to know more about is, how did you ensure that you didn't request all 65 Million Records within a single turn of the event loop?

Comment: There isn't much code to share, as this has basically become a devops problem. The naive node approach initially called cursor.next(), processed it, cursor.next() and so on. Then we realized that it was getting killed by network latency, so we used cursor.pipe() to an output stream that processed N records in parallel, which dramatically improved performance both because there was less back and forth to big table, and because big table is also clustered. We then maxed out the CPU on the box.

Comment: However, it was also obvious that mongo was being too slow as well from the behavior of all the other tools that we have tried to export with.

Comment: Once you have bson file generated using mongodump, you can use bsondump utility that comes out of the box with mongodb tar ball to convert the bson files to json directly. This json file can be uploaded to Big table

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know about the bsondump tool. I knew something like that had to exist, but I couldn't find it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue, I upgraded mongodb from 3.2 to 5.0.  now have to export all data and import.  What could be fastest solution to do so.